# Precompiled headers in Qt avoids recompiling modified header files

Tags: c++, qt

Using [pre-compiled headers in Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-precompiledheaders.html), it works and reduces the compile time of my project.
I've put common C++ and Qt header files in a file named `all.h` to avoid recompiling them in every translation unit:

```
#ifndef _ALL_H_
#define _ALL_H_

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
.
.
#include <QGlobal>
#include <QVector>
.
.
#endif
```

In addition I have some header files which they're changing frequently (I don't need them to be pre-compiled), but `qmake` doesn't recompile those headers and I have to rebuild whole the project thoroughly.

What's the problem? How can I modify my own header files and invoke the compile to recompile them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add these lines to your `.pro` file, I call it a bug in `qmake` (maybe):

```
DEPENDPATH += path_to_source
INCLUDEPATH += path_to_source
```

For example:

```
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .
```

Answer (score 0):

`qmake`, like any make utility needs to know what the sources of your application are. The .cpp sources are easy to figure out, but the .h sources need to be figured out. Also, modern make utilities want to know which header files affect which Translation units, so they can recompile only specific object files.

Comment: I have added the headers files which need to be recompiled in the `.pro` by `HEADERS`. when I doesn't use precompiled feature everything is fine. but after using it I have that issue.